# Download files from Dropbox shared folder using Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api

A friend sent me the URL of a dropbox folder he shared with me. This folder has files whose total size is about 8GB.

I have a basic account with 2GB limit, so I cannot add the shared folder contents to my dropbox folder.

How do I programmatically download all the files from the shared folder to my PC?

I checked the documentation (both v1 and v2) and didn't find any APIs that would do this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The current version of the Dropbox API, has endpoints for getting the metadata of shared links, as well as downloading files from shared links:

- to get the metadata for a shared link: [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata)
- to download files from a shared link: [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file)

The [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata) endpoint unfortunately doesn't return the file listing though, so if you need to programmatically get the file listing for use with [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file), as a workaround you can use the API v1 endpoint [/1/metadata/link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-link).

---

Edit:

Dropbox API v2 now supports listing the contents of a shared link for a folder. This can be accomplished using the same interface as listing a folder in a connected user's account, via the list_folder functionality. To list the contents of a shared link for a folder, you instead provide the shared link URL in the `shared_link` parameter to [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder).

If you're using an official SDK, there will also be a corresponding method for this endpoint.

Comment: get_shared_link_file is giving the following error: {
  "error_summary": "shared_link_access_denied/..",
  "error": {
    ".tag": "shared_link_access_denied"
  }
}

Comment: i am able to get the listing of the files in the shared folder using /1/metadata/link, but when i try downloading the file using /2/sharing/get_shared_link_file (passing the url as the folder url + file path), it is giving "shared_link_access_denied" error. Also, /2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata did not work for me, it gave 500 internal server error.

Comment: The `shared_link_access_denied` error means you're not allowed to access this shared link, e.g., the link is disabled or has access controls. The 500 sounds like a bug on our side though. Please share a sample so we can look into it: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/new?community_post%5Btopic_id%5D=200209245 or https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: I'm getting the shared_link_access_denied error too. Any user can access it via the URL, so there's no reason that the API should be access_denied. I saw this issue come up on the Dropbox forums, https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/shared-link-access-denied-when-trying-to-access-a-shared-file/td-p/286229 , and they acknowledge the bug there but have no ETA for fixing it.