# Fetch Image from dropbox to generate html by php OR by dropbox APi

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, dropbox-sdk-js

I want to fetch an image from a dropbox URL. The URL is below:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/afko74vlm19yimi/AAAJ03JqyS57nHpZlYjZm6zNa?dl=0

How can I use PHP/dropbox api to fetch this image from the above URL and use it in an HTML file?

Comment: There are multiple images there. I am not sure that I understand what you objective is. Do you want to display all images that are displayed when that link is clicked?

Comment: We will Display first four image on my Page by using url from code not after clicked

Comment: I am just looking at the source of the page now. It does look a bit complicated. I will see what I can come up with. Do you have any code currently?

Comment: No, We do not have any code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download files from Dropbox shared folder using Dropbox API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749266/download-files-from-dropbox-shared-folder-using-dropbox-api)

Comment: Hello Greg This is not possible duplicate